# Undefined method `destroy' for "Tech":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags

When I go to delete a post I keep receiving an error that says

> undefined method `destroy' for "Tech":String

The "tech" part of the posts varies with whatever the tag is of the post I am trying to delete. I am not sure what the problem is. I am using `acts_as_taggable_on` if that has anything to do with it.

This is my destroy method in my posts controller:

```
   def destroy
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @post.destroy

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
       format.xml  { head :ok }
       format.json { head :ok }
     end
   end
```

The delete button in my post show:

```
  <%= button_to 'Delete', @post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

Tags are saved in the database as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to give you an answer to fix your problem, because you are giving no code and no examples.

Nonetheless that error means you are calling the destroy method on a string, and strings in Ruby do not have a destroy method defined.

Check where are you calling destroy, because it seems you are doing it in some function that returns a string (a tag name in your case). You must do it on an object that is an instance of the Tag class.

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't initially specific I was hoping this was more an issue with the gem I was using that could be answered without code instead of an error in my code as I've used this code in other applications without the gem and have had no problem. As far as calling destroy on an object that is an instance could you show me an example of that. I'm still relatively new to programming so I'd appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, if you have an object like this: tag = Tag.new, then you can call its methods, for example: tag.getName, in this case it could return the name of the tag, which is a string. So if you do something like this: tag.getName.destroy you will be trying to destroy the returned string, not the tag itself. So you have the make sure to destroy the object: tag.destroy